# How to restrict the user not to enter specif words like "Kill, fight" on text field validation using Angular 6

Tags: html, angular6

i have validating the role with specific words not to accept as "Admin,Test,Tester, Head of Branch"

Since i am looking the right method to fix this using Angular 6 in my project. can someone provide me the solution to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### In Ts file define a variable:-

```
userValue: string;
```

---

### Then write a function:-

```
match() {
const restrictWord = ['Admin', 'Test', 'Tester', ' Head of Branch'];
for (let i = 0; i < restrictWord.length; i++ ) {
  if (this.userValue.match(restrictWord[i])) {
    this.userValue = '';
    alert('Plese Provide an Valid Value Only');
  }
}
```

}

---

In HTML File attach the variable and Function with textField:-

```
  <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Your Name" name="username" class="text_field" [(ngModel)]="userValue" (change)="match()">
```

Comment: You to change the value of this [(ngModel)]="userValue" or try to assign accData.Designation in function match ---------------------

match() {
const restrictWord = ['Admin', 'Test', 'Tester', ' Head of Branch'];
for (let i = 0; i < restrictWord.length; i++ ) {
  if (this.accData.Designation.match(restrictWord[i])) {
    this.accData.Designation = '';
    alert('Plese Provide an Valid Value Only');
  }
}

Comment: https://github.com/MNamir/Oddles_project/blob/master/src/app/Components/contact-form/contact-form.component.html

For HTML Check Line 8

Comment: https://github.com/MNamir/Oddles_project/blob/master/src/app/Components/contact-form/contact-form.component.ts       
For TS Check Line No. 17 and 63 to 71

Answer (score 0):

*Use This Function instead of that:-*

```
     match() {
     const restrictWord = ['dev', 'fool', 'test'];
     for (const word of restrictWord) {
     if (this.userValue) {
     if (this.userValue.toLowerCase().match(word)) {
      this.userValue = '';
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Okk but It's working in mine Project Built in Angular 8 can you please upload your form designs on codepen and attached the link here.So I can look into that.

Comment: sure, i will upload